# Верно ли данное согласование?

Tags: согласование

«75,5 штатных единиц». Верно согласование?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такая запись верна в том случае, если под 0,5 подразумевается половина:
*семьдесят пять с половиной **штатных единиц***.

Если же имеется в виду дробь (что вероятнее всего в деловом языке), то правильно использовать такую форму написания:
*семьдесят пять и пять десятых **штатной единицы***.

Таким образом, за прошедшие годы мною перенесено на помойку в числе прочих 204 ваших издания общим весом **75,5 килограмма**, на что затрачено тридцать два часа полезного времени. [Борис Левин. Инородное тело (1965-1994)]

Листовая площадь лесов и лугов превышает в десятки раз площадь насаждений, луговые травы наших широт ― в 22–38 раз, поле белой люцерны ― в **85,5 раза**, буковый лес ― **в 7,5 раза** и т. д. [В. И. Вернадский. Биосфера и ноосфера (1938)]

Вот что об этом сказано у [Розенталя](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5/):
правильными являются конструкции **35,5 процента** (не ...процентов), **12,6 километра** (не ...километров), **0,68 квадратного** (кв.) **метра** (не …метров),  т. е. при смешанном числе существительным управляет дробь, а не целое число; так же: **45,0** (сорок пять и ноль десятых) **секунды**, **6 7/8** (шесть и семь восьмых) **метра** и т. п.

В качестве примера приведу предложение с явной ошибкой.
*...по состоянию на декабрь 2019 года кадровый дефицит имеется во всех шести подстанциях скорой помощи Воронежа и в целом составляет: по врачам — **29,75 штатных единиц**, среднему медицинскому персоналу — 75,5 штатных единиц.*

Правильно: двадцать девять и *семьдесят пять сотых* (или *три четвертых* — нет разницы, все равно дробь) *штатной единицы*.